# .NET Core latency spikes - MySQL and Redis fails to connect occasionally

Tags: mysql, docker, asp.net-core, redis, .net-core

I'am running **.NETCore** app in **Docker** on Amazon Linux AMI (CentOS based) [running in amazon EC2 instance], **MySQL** database hosted on Amazon RDS and **Redis** hosted locally on same machine as .NETCore app

App is sitting behind **Apache** proxy

To connect to MySQL and Redis i use **MySql.Data** and **StackExchange.Redis** nuget packages

**Problem:**
App have huge latency spikes and sometimes fail with error

```
Connection id "0HLFB3QH78G7P", Request id "0HLFB3QH78G7P:00000001": 
An unhandled exception was thrown by the application.
StackExchange.Redis.RedisTimeoutException: Timeout performing ZREVRANGE globalLeaderboard, 
inst: 1, queue: 7, qu: 0, qs: 7, qc: 0, wr: 0, wq: 0, in: 7, ar: 0, 
clientName: RedisConnection, serverEndpoint: 172.17.0.1:6379, keyHashSlot:1809
```

Or with MySQL Connection Timeout error (don't have log on me right now)

[Graph from Grafana](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KCzL6.png)
where you can see the spikes

I've already tried different linux distributions and nginx instead of Apache but to no success

This is my RedisConnector base class from which all classes doing Redis operations inherit https://pastebin.com/aq7mDhk5

And this is my BaseDatabase base class from which all classes doing MySQL operations inherit https://pastebin.com/2639X5va

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem Solved

All problems was because i was using custom middleware that did some synchronous Database operations before calling `_next.Invoke()` and given that middleware is treated as singleton it probably blocked receiving thread.

Comment: At the end: it was combination of two factors, fist was synchronous calls, second was that oracle MysqlConnector is synchronous inside.

Use this instead: https://github.com/mysql-net/MySqlConnector